# Bug with apex:selectCheckboxes in Spring'13 release

Tags: checkbox, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Right now it seems that anything with the `<apex:selectCheckboxes>` wont work (regardless of version since I did try bumping it back on both the page and controller). See blog entry for full debugging steps:http://salesforcegirl.blogspot.hu/2013/05/bug-with.html

when trying to use a repeat to populate the Lists via maps it fails as well for both `<apex:selectCheckboxes>` and `<apex:selectList>`. But if you do it the long way, you can get `<apex:selectList>` to work at the very least, however not the `<apex:selectCheckboxes>` (which is what i need).

Here is the code:

```
public class sfg_testBugWithActionButton {

  public String fGrade {get; set;}
  public List<SelectOption> soGrade {get; set;}
  public String resultString {get; set;}

  public sfg_testBugWithActionButton() {
    createfilterMap();
    resultString = 'on Load of page';
  }

  public PageReference preformAction() {
    system.debug('Grade: ' + fGrade);//this wont be hit unless you use selectList
    resultString = 'button action preformed';
    return null;
  }

  private void createfilterMap() {
    soGrade = new List<SelectOption>();
    soGrade.add(new SelectOption('A', 'A'));
    soGrade.add(new SelectOption('B', 'B'));
    soGrade.add(new SelectOption('C', 'C'));
  }
```

}

Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="sfg_testBugWithActionButton">
  <apex:form>
  <apex:outputpanel id="mainWrap">

    <h2>Grade</h2>
    <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!fGrade}" layout="pageDirection">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!soGrade}" />
    </apex:selectCheckboxes>

    <apex:commandButton action="{!preformAction}" rerender="renderWrap" value="Submit Action" />
    <br />

    <apex:outputpanel id="renderWrap">
      {!resultString}
    </apex:outputpanel>

  </apex:outputpanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<apex:selectCheckboxes>` hold multiple values so its value needs to be an array of strings:

```
public List<String> fGrade {get; set;}
```

Then you just need to initialize it in the constructor, and the example in the question works:

```
this.fGrade = new List<String>();
```

Comment: even though its being initialized in the method called by the constructor and in their documentation it says it needs a list<SelectOption> ?

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_pages_selectoption.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_pages_selectoption.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: if not <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!fGrade}" layout="pageDirection">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!soGrade}" />
    </apex:selectCheckboxes> then how would you write it on the page?

Comment: The value of <apex:selectOptions> is a list of SelectOptions; the value of <apex:selectCheckboxes> is a list of Strings: http://markup.io/v/8hkqdm87yq5a  Nothing needs to be changed in the Visualforce page.

Comment: Sorry i see what you are saying but it seems odd that its necessary... otherwise you would have to do that to every var in order to use which is not the case... but it works for the single example..

Comment: So it works for everything except the map example, which is still broken for <apex:SelectList> as well.

Comment: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Bug-with-apex-selectCheckboxes-in-Spring13/m-p/626179/highlight/false#M115533

Comment: answer found :-) thanks man! http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/user/v1/viewprofilepage/user-id/38638